# Porting Xamarin to Maui - Custom control

Tags: xamarin, layout, controls, maui

I have a custom control `CustomView` with a couple of bindable properties

```
namespace App.Maui.Controls
{
   public class CustomView : Layout<Layout>
```

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="using:App.Maui.Controls">
  <controls:CustomView IsOpen="{Binding ViewModel.IsOpen}">
```

When porting my Xamarin app to Maui, the code compiles fine, but I get the following error when trying to display the control:

`Microsoft.Maui.Platform.HandlerNotFoundException: 'Handler not found for view App.Maui.Controls.CustomControl.'`

The error seems quite straight-forward but the solution eludes me - following a plethora of guides they never mention handlers, nor does it seem required to have platform specific implementations for a base control.

How do I define a handler for such a basic control?

Comment: Are you sure you want to extend `Layout<Layout>`? I think the new way to do it is just to use `Layout`. There are pre-defined handlers for `Layout`.

Comment: Could you please post the full code of `CustomView `?

Comment: I've rewritten it as a StackLayout, thank you.

Comment: Hi @Aventil, do you mean you've solved your problem? Congratulations.  Could you please share the solution so that it will help others who have similar problems? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to rewrite the classes to suit Maui's new way it handles custom controls.

I followed https://github.com/hartez/CustomLayoutExamples as a source.

Comment: Hi @Aventil, could you please mark your answer as accepted so that it will help others who have similar problems? Thanks in advance. :)